# Reload vue-owl-carousel after dynamic data update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, owl-carousel, vue-cli

Initialized a vue-owl-carousel using dynamic data

```
<script>

import carousel from 'vue-owl-carousel'

export default {
    components: { carousel },
}
```

```
<carousel :items="1">
    <img v-for="(img, index) in images" :src="img" :key="index">
  </carousel>


 data: function() {
    return {
      images: [
        "https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?1",
        "https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?2",
        "https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?3",
        "https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?4"
      ]
    };
  }
```

**Removed one of images from the images array**

How to update the owl carousel with new images array?

Comment: how you would like to remove the image from array? for example by clicking a button, refreshing the page, or ... ?

Answer (score 2):

This should work with normal reactivity so im guessing the way how the carousel library is built is just sloppy. My advice is to just build your own carousel. It is really not that and can be a good learning curve.

Nevertheless if you really want to use this library, you could wrap the carousel in a template with a v-if condition. Because when deleting a entry from the images array the carousel needs to be rerendered to show its changes. You can force this by deleting and adding the component to the DOM by toggling the v-if of the template tag. A hacky solution to a problem that shouldnt exist in the first place. But something like this would work:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <template v-if="toggle">
      <carousel :items="1">
        <template v-for="(img, index) in images">
          <img :src="img" :key="index" />
        </template>
      </carousel>
    </template>

    <button @click="deleteImage">DELETE A IMAGE</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Carousel from "vue-owl-carousel";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: { Carousel },
  data() {
    return {
      images: [
        "https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?1",
        "https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?2",
        "https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?3",
        "https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?4",
      ],
      toggle: true,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    deleteImage() {
      this.toggle = false;
      this.images.pop();
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.toggle = true;
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Ive tested it and it works with the vue-owl-carousel library see [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-owl-carousel-dynamic-2oowgg?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Actually i just thought of a better way, you could place the following in the carousel tag ":key=images.length" This ensures that whenever the images array changes the key of the carousel changes as well which triggers a rerender by vue, since a different key is seen as a different component.

Comment: Thank you so much bro. Binded ":key=images.length" with <carousel> component solved the issue.

Comment: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/many-ways-to-rerender-a-vue-component-660376d94cc1
After reading the section  (Another Bad Way — v-if Hack),
I realized that it is not better to implement the v-if Hack. Not sure whether it is right or wrong.

Comment: The final working code look like this
`<carousel :key="images.length" :items="1">
    <img v-for="(img, index) in images" :src="img" :key="index">
  </carousel>`